# webpack error when installing @keplr-wallet/cosmos, in a webpack bundled react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a simple react project which uses webpack as bundler and i am trying to work with @keplr-wallet/cosmos. As I install the package, it gives me a error related to webpack file loader which says:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently
> no loaders are configured to process this file.

I have my webpack configuration as below,

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = env => {
  const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/web', 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
  });
  
  const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/style.[contenthash:8].css',
    chunkFilename: 'css/[id].style.[contenthash:8].css',
  });
  
  return {
    entry: './src/web/index.tsx',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'), filename: '[name].[contenthash].js', publicPath: '/',
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
      modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
      alias: {
        Store: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/store/reducers'),
      },
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
        os: false,
        path: false,
      },
    },
    stats: {
      errorDetails: true,
      children: true,
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name (file) {
                  /*if (env === 'development') {
                    return '[path][name].[ext]'
                }*/
                  return '[name]_[hash].[ext]'
                },
                publicPath: '/public/assets/img/',
                outputPath: '../images/'
              }  
            }
          ]
        },
      ],
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      }),
      miniCssExtractPlugin,
      htmlPlugin,
      new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
      // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
      new CompressionPlugin({
        algorithm: 'gzip',
      }),
      new Dotenv()
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
      usedExports: true,
    },
  }
};
```

And my babel.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
    [
      '@babel/preset-react',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    ['@babel/preset-flow'],
  ],
};
```

Adding a screenshot of the error. I can understand that the issue is coming for the files which contains static keyword. I read about this in babel and as far as I have understood, it's available in @babel/preset-env. Here's a link to [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-static-block) which gives definition to static keywords. I don't understand what is causing this issue.

[image]

The versions of packages.

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12", 
"@babel/node": "^7.17.10",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.18.6",
```